# gcloud alpha pubsub subscriptions seek method not found exception

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a large backlog of undelivered messages for one Google Cloud Pub/Sub subscription.  I would rather not have to process every message to get caught up, and I cannot delete the subscription manually because is was created using Cloud Deployments.

The gcloud seek command appears to be what I need (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/pubsub/subscriptions/seek).  However, upon running this command in the Google Cloud Shell, I receive a "method not found" exception:

```
gcloud alpha pubsub subscriptions seek my_subscription__name --time=2016-11-11T06:20:57
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.pubsub.subscriptions.seek) Subscription [my_subscription__name:seek] not found: Method not found.
```

The subscription type is "Pull".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API for this method is white-list only at the moment -- but stay tuned. We'll find a way to clarify this in the CLI documentation or output.